# document.write doesn't display anything once the actual program finishes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, rounding

```
function median(list)
{
list.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
var list_len = list.length;

//Use  the modulus operator to determine whether the array's length is odd or even.
//Use Math.floor to truncate numbers
//Use Math.round to round numbers

if ((list_len % 2) == 1)
    return list[Math.floor(list_len / 2)];
else
    return Math.round((list[list_len / 2 - 1] + list[list_len /  2]) / 2);
} //end of function median

//Test driver
var my_list_1 = [8, 3, 9, 1, 4, 7];
var my_list_2 = [10, -2, 0, 5, 3, 1, 7];

 var med = median(my_list_1);

document.write("Median of [", my_list_1, "] is : ", med, "<br />");
med = median(my_list_2);
document.write("Median of [", my_list_2, "] is : ", med, "<br />");

document.write("Round of 6.5: ", Math.round(6.5));
```

I am running this program using Visual Studio 2012 ultimate.. I get all the results but finally i do not get the result for the last document.write on internet explorer.. Also when i tried to open it on google chrome, its working fine.. I am uploading the images to show you what i mean..

[image: code written in VS2012]

[image: Output IE]

[image: Output Google chrome]

Comment: document.write overwrites the document if it's called after the document has finished loading the first time, so it's almost never the right method to use

Comment: Its not clear.. All documents are loading accept the last one.. andi cant upload images because this stupid error about code format pops up